# Use gradle plugin to configure another gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, kotlin, gradle-plugin

I want to implement a gradle plugin which changes the `project.version` according to the configuration of the plugin and then use the changed `project.version` to configure another gradle plugin e.g. for building containers. The problem is now that both configurations are evaluated at the same time and therefore the changes to `project.version` are not applied at the time the second plugin is configured.

I search the Gradle documentation but found nothing regarding my problem.

build.gradle

```
class VersionPluginExtension {
    String major
    String minor
    String patch
}

class VersionPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        def extension = project.extensions.create('versionPlugin', VersionPluginExtension)
        project.afterEvaluate {
            project.version = "${extension.major}.${extension.minor}.${extension.patch}"
        }
        project.task('showVersion') {
            doLast {
                println "${project.version}"
            }
        }
    }
}

class ContainerPluginExtension {
    String version
}

class ContainerPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        def extension = project.extensions.create('containerPlugin', ContainerPluginExtension)
        project.task('build') {
            doLast {
                println "${extension.version}"
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: VersionPlugin
apply plugin: ContainerPlugin

versionPlugin {
    major = '1'
    minor = '1'
    patch = '1'
}

containerPlugin {
    version = project.version
}
```

I expect that the task build returns `1.1.1` and not `unspecified` but I think it's not possible in this way. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem above looks like this:

```
class VersionPluginExtension {
    String major
    String minor
    String patch
    private String version

    String getVersion() {
        if (!version)
            return "${major}.${minor}.${patch}"
        return version
    }
}

class VersionPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        def extension = project.extensions.create('versionPlugin', VersionPluginExtension)

        project.task('showVersion') {
            doLast {
                println "${extension.version}"
            }
        }
    }
}

class ContainerPluginExtension {
    String version
}

class ContainerPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        def extension = project.extensions.create('containerPlugin', ContainerPluginExtension)

        project.task('build') {
            doLast {
                println "${extension.version}"
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: VersionPlugin
apply plugin: ContainerPlugin

versionPlugin {
    major = '1'
    minor = '1'
    patch = '1'
}

project.version = versionPlugin.version

containerPlugin {
    version = project.version
}
```

Result:

```sh
> Configure project :
1.1.1

> Task :showVersion
1.1.1

> Task :build
1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the definition of `version` from the `containerPlugin` block to the plugin definition :

```
class ContainerPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        def extension = project.extensions.create('containerPlugin', ContainerPluginExtension)
        project.afterEvaluate {
            extension.version = project.version
        }
        project.task('build') {
            doLast {
                println "${extension.version}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result :

```
$ gradle build

> Task :build
1.1.1
```

Comment: Thanks that's valid solution if I develop both plugins! But what if the second plugin is a third-party plugin which gets the configuration via the extension? Isn't there a way to order plugin execution?